# bimomial theorem find value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

I am given the question:

> What is the value of the following? $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^5\binom{5}{k}4^{5-k}(-2)^k$$

I missed class when the teacher went over a similar problem, but I know we have to use the binomial theorem.  I'm not sure which value she means we have to get...

Comment: Hint: try to identify what $x$ and $y$ are in $\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n} \binom{n}{j} x^j y^{n-j}$.

Comment: that would be x=4 and y=-2?

Comment: @vera Welcome to math.stackexchange.  In the future, please do not just link to images of questions (*many people won't bother clicking links either out of laziness, malice, or they are afraid of contracting viruses or some other reason*) but instead try to learn how to [type your mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on the site like I have in the edit.  The link I provide contains a primer on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here making your posts much more readable.  Further, its a good skill to develop for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\sum_{k=0}^5 \binom {5}{k}4^{5-k} (-2)^k = (4+(-2))^5 = 2^5 $.
See also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem.